# IOException with SAXParser

Tags: android

### **the next code should parse a data from a webService to textView;

**Problem**: IOEXception **Q**: how can I solve the Exception and make my program work correct??** so can anyone help me cause I tryied many sample codes from net but nothing worked with me

```
 @Override
 public class NewParsActivity extends Activity {   

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
         Button b;

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        static final String baseUrl="http://www.androidpeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/example.xml";

        TextView tv;
        EditText ed,ed2;


            tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
            ed=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt);
            b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            ed2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

            try{



                SAXParserFactory spf=SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                SAXParser sp=spf.newSAXParser();
                XMLReader xr=sp.getXMLReader();
                URL link=new URL(baseUrl);
                handlXml doingWork=new handlXml();
                xr.setContentHandler(doingWork);
                xr.parse(new InputSource(link.openStream()));
                String information=doingWork.getInformation();
                tv.setText(information);
            }catch(Exception e){
             tv.setText("Error");
            }



    //
    public class handlXml  extends DefaultHandler {
       One  item=new One();

       public String getInformation(){
           return item.DataToString();

       }
    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(localName.equals("website")){
            String uniN=attributes.getValue("category");
            item.setName(uniN);
        }
    }

}

    //

public class One {

    String UName;
    public void setName(String n){
        UName=n;    
    }


public String DataToString()
{
    return "In"+UName;
}
}
```

Comment: in which line IOException occurred , pls edit your code so we can know that from which line that exception occured

Comment: xr.parse(new InputSource(link.openStream()))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you have implemented the handler correctly? You still lack `characters()` and `endElement()`.

`startElement()` is only used to identify the tag you're reading. Use a temporary variable to store stuff in `characters()`, and save the data in `endElement()`.

Maybe that is the problem. I'm not sure.

Comment: what are these is this a defiened classes in the library

Comment: If you don't override these, they're supplied by the parent class.  This is not the problem.

Comment: @DonRoby but if they are supplied by the parent, they do nothing. How are you going to store the value in the XML?
[source: java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html)

Comment: It may well not be correctly implemented, though sometimes all the info you need is in the start tag attributes.  But this doesn't cause the IOException.

Comment: mmmm  so it's not the problem:|